# fprintd-enroll works with right-index finger only

Tags: security, fingerprint

When I try any other finger with:

```
%> fprintd-enroll left-index-finger
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
failed to claim device: Not Authorized: net.reactivated.fprint.device.setusername
```

It doesn't work for me;

But if I don't specify finger (which uses right-index by default):

```
%> fprintd-enroll 
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Enrolling right index finger.
```

It works

Running on Arch Linux , and packages installed from aur:

```
fprintd 0.4.1-4
libfprint 0.4.0-3
```

**UPDATE**

```
%> fprintd-enroll -f left-index-finger
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Enrolling right index finger.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is only supported as of fprintd 0.5.1: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libfprint/fprintd/commit/?id=7eb1f0fd86a4168cc74c63b549086682bfb00b3e

When I build fprintd 0.5.1, the `-f` option does work correctly.

Comment: Yes, 0.5.1 works!

Answer (score 2):

From the fprintd man page:

`fprintd-enroll [username]`
and
`-f finger

For fprintd-enroll, the finger to enroll`

It looks like you are placing "left-index-finger" as the username. and the user left-index-finger is Not Authorized